# Why use tf.mul in the word2vec training process?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

The Word2vec model uses noise-contrastive estimation (NCE) loss to train the model.

Why does it use `tf.mul` in the true sample logit calculation, but uses `tf.matmul` in the negative calculation?

See the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L248).

Comment: FYI: `tf.mul` has been changed to `tf.multiply`. See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply

Answer (score 0):

One way you can think of the NCE loss calculation is as a batch of independent, binary logistic regression classifications problems. In both cases we are performing the same calculations, even though it does not look like it at the first place.

To show you that we are actually calculating the same thing, assume  the follwoing for the true input part:

```
emb_dim    = 3 # dimensions of your embedding vector 
batch_size = 2 # number of examples in your trainings batch
vocab_size = 6 # number of total words in your text 
               # (so your word ids range from 0 - 5)
```

Furthermore, assume the following training example in your batch:

```
1 => 0 # given word with word_id=1, I expect word with word_id=0 
1 => 2 # given word with word_id=1, I expect word with word_id=2
```

Then your embedding matrix [example_emb](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L235) has the dimensions [2,3] and your true weight matrix [true_w](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L238) also has the dimensions [2,3], and should look like this:

```
example_emb = [ [e1,e2,e3], [e1,e2,e3] ] # [2,3]  input word
true_w      = [ [w1,w2,w3], [w4,w5,w5] ] # [2,3]  target word
```

The example_emb is a subset of the total word embeddings ([emb](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L201)) that you are tryin to learn, and true_w is a a subset of the weights ([smb_w_t](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L201)). Each row in example_emb represents and input vector , and each row in the weight represent a target vector.

So [e1,e2,e3] is the word vector of the input word with word_id = 1 taken from emb, and [w1,w2,w3] is the word vector of the expected target word with word_id = 0.

Now  intuitively stated, the classification task you are trying to solve is: given i see input word and target word is this observation correct?

The two classification tasks then are (without the bias, and tensorflow has this handy 'sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits' function, which applies the sigmoid later):

```
logit( 1=>0 ) = dot( [e1,e2,e3], transpose( [w1,w2,w3] )   =>
logit( 1=>0 )  = e1*w1 + e2*w2 + e3*w3  
    
and

logit( 1=>2 )  = dot( [e1,e2,e3], transpose( [w4,w5,w6] )   =>
logit( 1=>2 )  = e1*w4 + e2*w5 + e3*w6
```

We can calculate [[logit(1=>0)],[logit(1=>2)]] the easiest if we perform an element-wise multiplication tf.mul() and then summing up each row.

The output of this calculations will be a [batch_size, 1] matrix containing the logits for the correct words. We do know the ground truth/label (y') for this examples, which is 1 because these are the correct examples.

```
true_logits = [ 
  [logit(1=>0)], # first input word of the batch 
  [logit(1=>2)]  # second input word of the batch
]
```

Now for the second part of your question why you we use tf.matmul() in the negative sampling, let's assume that we draw 3 negative samples (num_sampled=3). So [sampled_ids](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L225) = [3,4,5].

Intuitively, this means that you add six more training examples to your batch, namely:

```
1 => 3 # given word_id=1, do i expect word_id=3? No, because these are negative examples.
1 => 4
1 => 5
1 => 3 # second input word is also word_id=1
1 => 4
1 => 5
```

So you look up your [sampled_w](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L243), which turns out to be a [3, 3] matrix. Your parameters now look like this:

```
example_emb = [ [e1,e2,e3], [e1,e2,e3] ] # [2,3]  input word
sampled_w   = [ [w6,w7,w8], [w9,w10,w11], [w12,w13,w14] ] # [3,3]  sampled target words
```

Similar to the true case, what we want is the logits for all negative training examples. E.g., for the first example:

```
logit(1 => 3) = dot( [e1,e2,e3], transpose( [w6,w7,w8] )   =>
logit(1 => 3) = e1*w6 + e2*w7 + e3*w8
```

Now in this case, we can use the matrix multiplication after we transpose the sampled_w matrix. This is achieved using the transpose_b=True parameter in the tf.matmul() call. The transposed weight matrix looks like this:

```
sampled_w_trans   = [ [w6,w9,w12], [w7,w10,w13], [w8,w11,w14] ] # [3,3]
```

So now the tf.matmul() operation will return a [batch_size, 3] matrix, where each row are the logits for one example of the input batch. Each element represents a logit for a classification task.

The whole result matrix of the negative sampling contains this:

```
sampled_logits = [ 
  [logit(1=>3), logit(1,4), logit(1,5)], # first input word of the batch 
  [logit(1=>3), logit(1,4), logit(1,5)]  # second input word of the batch
]
```

The labels / ground truth for the sampled_logits are all zeros, because these are the negative examples.

In both cases we perform the same calculation, that is the calculation for a binary classification logistic regression (without the sigmoid, which is applied later).